# issue with if condition for variable

Tags: php

I have two parameters in my stored procedure i.e. @startdate and @enddate. The user selects startdate from text box and enddate also from text box. Then click submit.

I want to make sure if user leaves blank both the boxes, it should display data for the whole current month i.e. 01/08/2012 to 31/08/2012 now.

If user just selects date in any one of the boxes, the other text box should have the same value.

So I have declared variable as below and tried the condition but it always display data for whole month irrespective of what date is selected. I think there is a problem with my if condition.

```
$startdate = isset($_REQUEST['startdate']) ? $_REQUEST['startdate'] : null;
$enddate   = isset($_REQUEST['enddate']) ? $_REQUEST['enddate'] : null;
if (empty($startdate)) {
    $startdate = $enddate;
}
if (empty($enddate)) {
    $enddate   = $startdate;
}
if (empty($startdate))
    ;
if (empty($enddate))
    ;
$startdate = '01/08/2012';
$enddate   = '31/08/2012';
```

Comment: `if(empty($startdate));` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you handle this in the stored procedure?

Comment: No matter what happens, `$startdate = '01/08/2012'; $enddate   = '31/08/2012';` resets `$startdate` and `$enddate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last two `if` statements have no influence of the program flow. You always set `$startdate` and `$enddate` to the specified dates.

You need:

```
if(empty($startdate)) $startdate = '01/08/2012';
if(empty($enddate)) $enddate = '31/08/2012';
```

If you want to get the first and last day of the actual month every time you could use something like this:

```
if(empty($startdate)) $startdate = date('01/m/Y', strtotime("-1 month"));
if(empty($enddate)) $enddate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("-1 month"));
```

Comment: That's *if* OP wants `$startdate` to default to '01/01/2012' and `$enddate` to default to '31/08/2012'.

Comment: Thanks to every one...It worked after I changed my code as per your answers...exactly i expect every month it should automatically change startdate and enddate for e.g. 01/09/2012  and 31/09/2012 for september...is it possible?.

Comment: I edited the answer to get you the first/last day of the actual month as well.

Comment: @fdomig Thank you but I think there is a minor mistake in your code....it displays from Aug 10 to August 31...not from Aug 01..FYI..my date column is varchar(50) in my table.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
$startdate = isset($_REQUEST['startdate']) ? $_REQUEST['startdate'] : "";
$enddate = isset($_REQUEST['enddate']) ? $_REQUEST['enddate'] : "";

if (empty($startdate) && (empty($enddate)) {
    $startdate = '01/08/2012';
    $enddate = '31/08/2012';
} elseif (empty($startdate) {
    $startdate = $enddate;
} elseif (empty($enddate) {
    $enddate = $startdate;
}
```

If both are empty, it uses the start and end of this month; if one or the other is empty, it uses the value for the other.

Answer (score 1):

The logic was not correct. This should work.

```
$startdate = isset($_REQUEST['startdate']) ? $_REQUEST['startdate'] : null;
$enddate = isset($_REQUEST['enddate']) ? $_REQUEST['enddate'] : null;

if (empty($startdate)) {
$startdate  = $enddate ;
}
elseif (empty($enddate)) {
$enddate = $startdate;
}
elseif(empty($startdate) && empty($enddate)) {
$startdate = '01/08/2012';
$enddate = '31/08/2012';
}
```